# Check memory consume of vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting a System.OutOfMemoryException from my vb.net application, it happened from one certain user. I am trying to figure out whether my application takes too much memory space or the PC has low memory. But she just upgraded her desktop as i3 Intel CPU and higher memory.

Is there any tool that I check memory consumption when code is executed as go through lines?

By the way, it is developed by vs2010 and It is a Windows application.

<--Edit-->
I found the problem from my application. I did not mention because I did not know what the problem was. I am using a Google map inside of vb.net application. It takes a memory whenever I search a map on web browser which is on a form . Even though I close the form, it is not disappeared from 
memory. It is just going up. That goes away when I close MDI form. FYI..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best tool we've worked so far is the JetBrains profiler (http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/).

Comment: Have you tried the free version? or should I purchase the full version in order to track the memory consumption that I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Well! Never mind. The free version is only for open source project.

Comment: They offer a 10-days trial version. AFAIK, we've used both the trial and the licensed versions (some developers in our team have the license, some do not).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182389.aspx says VS 2010 has a profiler included, but we've never used it.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common error. It normally happens when the application enters a loop that never ends... (infinite loop).

Is it a Console, WinForms, ASP, WPF?
Try to identify during which Event your application throws the exception and put a try catch to print out more details.

Comment: The most important cause for such errors is the use of large sized array, which are allocated in LOH (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just check out this cool WPF performance suite to check out if you have memory leaks:

[Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx)

[image: WPF Performance suite]

Or check out if you can use `GC.Collect()` to find the leak.

Also you can accecss in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to any .Net memory data and peaks.

[image: Process Explorer]

Regards